# Reference Error newDate is not defined?

Tags: javascript, date, defined

I get the Error Message:"Uncaught ReferenceError: newDate is not defined" Why?

```
<script>
var str = newDate('1992-05-02');
alert(str);
</script>
```

Comment: Add a space: `new Date(...);`

Answer (score 3):

`new Date`

not

`newDate`

You're instantiating a constructor called `Date`.

Comment: You're not instantiating a constructor. You're *calling* (or invoking) a constructor and *instantiating* a new instance of a Date object.